# On Xenial, certain websites have a link to a pdf, but doesn't display the pdf

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, pdf

Using Xenial with Chrome v55, some websites have a link to a webpage displaying a pdf file. However, the pdf file only displays as blank. Firefox works OK however. As an example, the URL of the pdf link is 
https://www.direct.aviva.co.uk/direct/Document/MMV300464692/Retrieve/31

Comment: There's no point in adding a link only you can use.  The others would have to login.

Comment: I realise that. But I have no idea on how to set this up as I don't own that website.

Comment: I forgot to say that when I clikc the pdf's link, it first displays "FLASH CONTENTE" and "Click to Activate Flash" as well as a symbol of a red circle with a diagonal red stripe across it as well as a black "f" overlapping it. When I click, the screen goes black. NB this activation of flash works OK on other webpages which do not have links to pdf files i.e. they merely display a graphic when the symbol is clicked.

Comment: You have malware. Check your Chrome addons before anything else.

Comment: Thanks, CelticWarrior. Removing Flash Block (Plus) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by CelticWarrior, I checked my Chrome add-ons and Removing Flash Block (Plus) solved the problem.

I clicked **Tools > Extensions**. I then clicked the Dustbin icon to remove the Flash Block (Plus) extension. I'd been using that extension in order to avoid looking at Adobe Flash junk. However, it's not really needed nowadays as relatively few websites use Adobe Flash.